# Working with capacitive buttons in Android

Tags: android

I was curious if there is any library to work with the capacitive buttons of Samsung phones??
I mean to light them up when an event occurs, or blink them, stuffs like that...

Thanks,
rohitkg

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing in the Android SDK for this, as there is no assumption that such buttons exist, have backlights, etc. You are welcome to contact device manufacturers to see if they have a documented and supported means of doing this for their specific devices.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a code snippet I grabbed from [samsung-moment-notifications](http://code.google.com/p/samsung-moment-notifications/source/browse/trunk/MomentNotificationLight/src/com/geniusdog/monotlights/NotificationLights.java).

```
Process process = null;
DataOutputStream os = null;
try {
    // get root 
    process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
    os = new DataOutputStream(process.getOutputStream());
    // write the command
    os.writeBytes("echo 100 > /sys/class/leds/button-backlight/brightness\n");
    os.writeBytes("exit\n");
    // clear the buffer
    os.flush();
    Toast.makeText(NotificationLights.this, "Lights are on", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    // wait for complete
    process.waitFor();

     // won't catch an error with root, but it has to have an exception catcher to execute
 } catch (Exception e) {
     Toast.makeText(NotificationLights.this, "Couldn't get SU, are you rooted?", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       return;
 }
```

1- You must have a rooted device.

2- You must know the location of the script which turns the lights on/off for each device.

`/sys/class/leds/button-backlight/brightness` is specific to the *Samsung Moment*.

If you were to try it on another device it wouldn't work.